# WPF Grid MinHeight/MinWidth 'Auto' analogue?

Tags: wpf, layout, grid, resize

Very commonly, inside a grid the layout behavior I want for a row/column is to have a minimum height/width that sizes exactly to the largest contained control's dimensions, but will also allow for automatically sizing larger if space is available. This is so common that I feel like this should be the default behavior, honestly, but I can't even seem to achieve it at all.

The scaling/resizing behavior I want is achieved through setting a row/column definition to a width/height of '*', the 'size to fit' behavior through using 'Auto' instead, and there is indeed a min width/height property; however this minimum does not accept 'Auto' as in input, so while something like `<RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="Auto"/>` would achieve the effect I want if it worked, it does not.

The workaround I've been using is to simply manually set the minimum dimension with some hardcoded value that seems appropriate, but for several obvious reasons this is far less desirable than having the code do the sizing for you.

Is there a good way of doing this in the general case that I am overlooking? I expect it will probably require an extra hoop or two to jump through (e.x. custom class extending grid to get the functionality I want) but hopefully I'm just missing something obvious.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this is a solution to your problem, but check out SharedSizeGroup.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.sharedsizegroup?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-windows-controls-definitionbase-sharedsizegroup

Comment: appreciate the idea (hadn't heard of that class before), but alas, I don't think this is particularly relevant to my issue.